# Use the developed bigram model to simulate sentences of text at least 5 words long

Tags: python

I have been given a question what is the title. I have spoken to the lecture and he told me for the generatation of the sentences i need to make a for loop, however as i have started writing and the code for the bigram and the for loop, however the for loop part i can't make any sense of. i have got a couple bits, but i just don't really understand how to move past the first calling of my input word. any help would be great.

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd
import string

file_name = 'Textbook.txt'
fd = open(file_name, encoding='utf8')
book = fd.read()
fd.close()
#print(book)

def clean_words(text):
unwanted = str.maketrans('', '', (string.punctuation))
return text.translate(unwanted)

def bigram(book):
book = clean_words(book)
book = book.lower()
words = book.split()
pairs = zip(words,words[1:])
bigram_words = Counter(pairs)

freq = list(bigram_words.values())
bigram = list(bigram_words)

first = []
second = []
for i in bigram:
    first.append((i[0]))
    second.append((i[1]))
    
return(pd.DataFrame({'First':first,'Second':second,'Frequency':freq}))

bigram_df = bigram(book)
print(bigram_df)


First_Word = input("")

for word in list(bigram_df['First']):
if word == First_Word:
```